# ffmpeg can't stop, when running with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, centos

when i use local ffmpeg, it exit normally.

```
cmd = f'ffmpeg -nostdin -vsync 0 -i {sec_replace(video_path)} -r {marked_paras.get_divide_frame_fps()}' \
      f'-q:v 2 -f image2 {crop_info} {sec_replace(default_frames_dir)}%08d.png'
logger.info(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# p.communicate()
command.utp_command("ps aux | grep ffmpeg")
timer = Timer(60, p.kill)
try:
    timer.start()
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
finally:
    timer.cancel()
command.utp_command("ffmpeg --version")
logger.info("stdout: {}".format(stdout))
logger.info("stdout: {}".format(stderr))
```

local stdout
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0

```
stdout: b"ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)\n  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox\n  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100\n  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100\n  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100\n  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100\n  libavfilter    =-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.71x    \r[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 231 >= 231\nframe=  281 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.90 bitrate=N/A speed=0.708x    \rframe=  291 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.23 bitrate=N/A speed=0.706x    \r[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 247 >= 247\nframe=  300 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.50 bitrate=N/A speed=0.698x    \r[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 261 >= 261\nframe=  312 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.86 bitrate=N/A speed=0.699x    \r[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 276 >= 276\nframe=  325 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.26 bitrate=N/A speed=0.702x    \rframe=  335 fps= 24 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.60 bitrate=N/A speed= 0.7x    \r[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 290 >= 290\n[image2 @ 0x7fd891906080] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 305 >= 305\nframe=  344 fps= 24 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.23 bitrate=N/A speed=0.708x    \nvideo:1096936kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown\n"
```

But when i put it in cloud. it can't stop the subprocess and blocking in communicate util being killed

remote output
ffmpeg version 3.4.11 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

```
stdout: b"ffmpeg version 3.4.11 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)\n  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect\n  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100\n  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100\n  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100\n  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100\n  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100\n  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0\n  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100\n  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100\n  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100\nInput #0, matroska,webm, from 'case.videoquality.recommend_video_quality_performance_case.recommend_video_quality_test/record_video/com.tencent.mtt/1667903766/test.mkv':\n  Metadata:\n    COMMENT         : Recorded by scrcpy 1.24\n    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100\n  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A\n    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x2240, 1k fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)\nUsing -vsync 0 and -r can produce invalid output files\nStream mapping:\n  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))\nPress [q] to stop, [?] for help\nOutput #0, image2, to 'case.videoquality.recommend_video_quality_performance_case.recommend_video_quality_test/record_video/com.tencent.mtt/1667903766/frames_end/%08d.png':\n  Metadata:\n    COMMENT         : Recorded by scrcpy 1.24\n    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100\n    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1080x2240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png\nframe=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=N/A speed=0.109x    \r[image2size=N/A time=00:00:17.06 bitrate=N/A speed=0.296x    \r[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 512 >= 512\n[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 514 >= 514\nframe=  703 fps= 12 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.20 bitrate=N/A speed=0.295x    \r[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 516 >= 516\n[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 517 >= 517\n[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 518 >= 518\nframe=  711 fps= 12 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.36 bitrate=N/A speed=0.295x    \r[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 520 >= 520\n[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 521 >= 521\n[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 522 >= 522\nframe=  717 fps= 12 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.46 bitrate=N/A speed=0.293x    \r[image2 @ 0x1a3e900] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 524 >= 524\n"
```

i want to stop the subprocess by ffmpeg self in cloud

Comment: when i running in local, it will out put this: video:1096936kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown. but in cloud it can't stop

Comment: Why are you even running `communicate()`? Just run `wait()`. You can take it further and just call `subprocess.run()`. If it hangs, see if updating cloud FFmpeg to the matching version help. A ton has changed since v3.4, including performance.